# How to find top n products based on number of items sold

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

How to find the top n products based on number items sold.
We can use max heap to keep track of number of times product was sold and find the top n from the heap. But the problem is let's say we have to find in real time when a product is brought we have to update the count and then heapify. Finding the product in heap is again O(N), deleting the product and adding back the product with updated count is O(LogN)
Is there any better solution?

Comment: Instead of using a heap as your only data structure, use another as well that has the same objects, for example a hashmap.

Comment: Problem with hashmap is finding top n elements, we have to sort and find which is O(nlogn)

Comment: Use the hashmap to look up the product and to update the count.  Use the heap to retrieve the top product.

Comment: Put your products in both data structures, as I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

There is rather simple data structure based on binary heap - indexed (indirect) binary heap. You have some **objects in an array**, their **indices** are in heap, this heap is ordered by some object property/complex key. So you can easily update object keys, keeping heap in order. **Seeking is not needed**.

This structure is described, for example, in the book **Algorithms** of Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
Very simple end concise implementation [is available online](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/IndexMaxPQ.java.html)

Note that retrieving of top `n` products takes `nlogN` time. If you have to know top n at every step, consider also approach with **two** heaps - like hour glass - lower one is max-heap, upper one is min-heap. When upper heap top (really bottom) becomes smaller than top of lower heap, exchange these items.

(Alike aproach is sometimes used in algorithms of online median determination, so you may also look at corresponding questions)